# How to unpack nested numpy.ndarray?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nested, numpy-ndarray

Suppose I have a numpy array `e` constructed as follow:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2])
b = np.array([3,4])
c = np.array([5,6])
d = np.array([7,8])
e = np.empty((2,2), dtype=object)

e[0,0] = a
e[0,1] = b
e[1,0] = c
e[1,1] = d

>>> e
array([[array([1, 2]), array([3, 4])],
   [array([5, 6]), array([7, 8])]], dtype=object)
```

I don't know how to unpack the array `e` so that it becomes:

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
   [5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Building an array like that `e` array in the first place is usually a mistake. Consider changing the code that produces `e`.

Comment: hello ito. I think what you're trying to do is "flatten" arrays which contain multiple arrays into one. You can use the + sign to combine two arrays, or checkout an existing stackoverflow question about flattening nested arrays.

Comment: @c8999c3f964f64 Adding two numpy arrays will try to broadcast them to compatible shapes, and add them elementwise. You cannot concatenate numpy arrays using  `+`.

Comment: I was thinking of array([1, 2] + [3, 4]), are you sure this wouldnt work in numpy? sry for assuming otherwise!

Comment: @c8999c3f964f64 `array([1,2] + [3,4])` is manipulation of `list`s not `numpy.ndarray`s. It works differently than `array([1,2]) + array([3,4])`

Comment: I usually recommend `np.stack` for this.

Comment: @c8999, + concatenates lists, but not numpy arrays.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`numpy.block`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.block.html#numpy.block):

```
e = np.block([[a,b],[c,d]])
print(e)
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

Comment: That is very nice. Looks like useful syntactic sugar for my convoluted `vstack` + `hstack` method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to stack your arrays properly:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2])
b = np.array([3,4])
c = np.array([5,6])
d = np.array([7,8])
e = np.vstack((np.hstack((a, b)), np.hstack((c, d))))
```